# Conditional point size?

Tags: plot, formatting, wolfram-mathematica, conditional-statements

I want to make a plot with different point sizes, but I don't know where to start.

First of all, I need error bars. My data is in a table that I have read from a .txt file. The following gets me what I need: the plot with corresponding error bars.

```
    d = ReadList["/.../data.txt", Number, RecordLists -> True];
    data = Table[{{d[[i, 5]], d[[i, 2]]}, ErrorBar[d[[i, 4]]]}, {i, 1, 16}];
    ErrorListPlot[data]
```

However, now I want to change the point size depending on an *additional* column from the .txt file. This means I have to add a column to my "data" table, but the error bars don't work when I do this.

So my question is: how do I set up a conditional PointSize which depends on a corresponding value in the text file while still keeping the error bars?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21717/x-y-scatter-plot-with-coloring-dependent-on-z-value/21721#21721

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can adapt this. I built this from the first basic example in the documentation for ErrorListPlot.

```
In[1]:= data = Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5], RandomReal[0.05]}, {i, 10}];
  Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
  bars = ErrorListPlot[Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]]} &, data]];
  dots = Graphics[Map[{PointSize[#[[3]]],Point[{#[[1]],#[[1]]}]}&,data]];
  Show[bars, dots]

Out[5]= ...PlotSnipped...
```

That does the standard Mathematica trick of overlaying two simpler graphics to get the result that you want.